# Calling C program and providing two inputs through bash

Tags: c, bash

I'm trying to input two arguments "listen" and "silent" to my C code through bash.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm just stuck on the re-direction mainly how to do line 5 of my bash.

```
#Clear screen
clear
gcc -o anagram anagram.c
#./anagram listen silent
if [ './anagram listen silent' -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "Test succeeded"
else
        echo "Test failed"
        fi
```

and this is part of my C

```
    char inputTwo[100]; //Second input is cahracter with array size 100
    printf("Input first word: "); //Prints string
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", inputOne);
    printf("Input second word: "); //Prints string
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", inputTwo);
    if (lengthChar(inputOne) == lengthChar(inputTwo)) //Checks length of string
        {
        toLowerCase(inputOne); //Sets inputOne and inputTwo to lower case
        toLowerCase(inputTwo);
        if (sumChar(inputOne) == sumChar(inputTwo)) //Checks the sum of the character arrays and compares
                {
                        printf("Code 0, the two inputs are anagrams\n");
                        return 0;
            }
                else if (sumChar(inputOne) != sumChar(inputTwo))
        {
                        printf("Code 1, the two inputs are not anagrams\n");
                        return 1;
                        }
    }   
    else
        printf("Number of characters not the same\n"); //If they don't have the same number of characters, returns code 1
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: I should note, that every time I try to run my bash script it gives me an error saying that an integer is expected where anagram is

Comment: Wait never mind I figured it out

Comment: Argument passing is part of any C tutorial. If you have problems with that, please be more precise when asking. Also, extract a [mcve] from your code. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

`'./anagram listen silent'` is a string, not executing a program. To catch the output of running a program, use `$()`, for example `$(./anagram listen silent)`.

However, your C code doesn't accept this kind of argument passing. You are reading input totally from `stdin`, not from the command line param.

The way for accepting command line param is to declare main function `int main()` as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` (`char **argv` is also OK), then use `argv` to get the command line param.

Your code only accepts input from `stdin` (using `scanf`), then you may have to pass input by calling the program like `echo -e "listen\nsilent" | ./anagram`. Wrap with `$()` to catch output is also OK.

**Update:** Noticed that you are willing to get the return value of the executed program instead of the `stdout` output, then you can use `> /dev/null` to eat the `stdout` output, then use `$?` to get return value, for example `echo -e "listen\nsilent" | ./anagram > /dev/null; echo $?`.

Answer (score 1):

As your C reads on `stdin` and not [via command line arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24684/confusing-use-of-and-operators), employing a ["here document"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) and simple shell [list tests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24684/confusing-use-of-and-operators) works quite succinctly.

```
./anagram <<EOW && echo "Test succeeded" || echo "Test Failed"
listen
silent
EOW
```